# Конкатенация в запросе sql

Tags: sql

Вопрос как я могу сделать конкатенацию переменной и текста.

```
Например 'Пациент '+@Name
```

Так выводит ошибку преобразования varchar в int

Comment: [Это зависит от типа БД](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Functions_and_expressions/String_functions) - укажите ваш диалект SQL

Comment: Я уже нашел, спасибо

Comment: сюда будут приходить люди с поисковиков и минусовать ваш ответ, если для их СУБД ваше решение не работает (т.к. единственная метка `[sql]` подразумевает что это должно работать для любой СУБД) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT ('VarValue' + CAST(32 AS VARCHAR))

Comment: Неплохой тип данных для переменной с именем @Name.